# How to set numbers alone to a different font in a document

Tags: math-mode, fonts

Is it possible to set numbers wherever present (like figure number, table number, etc.) in a document to different font. I am currently using times new roman font via package "times". With this font number present in the document looks like

[image]

But if I use number inside math environment in latex, I get

[image]

Is there any way to turn numbers along into different font in latex.

Comment: Keerthi, someone may know a way to automatically typeset numerals in a given font throughout your document, but meanwhile:  it is my practice to place numerals inside a math environment whenever they are values related to the math (eg in a table or within the text, like "...the acceleration is $20.2$\,m\,s$^{-2}$ through the turn...").  That way, math numbers are intentionally distinct from other numbers like "Chapter 2" or "Fig 13".  Just a thought, which you have probably considered.

Answer (score 2):

As you've discovered, the `times` package changes only the *text-mode* font, but not the *math-mode* font, to a clone of Times Roman.

Bby the way, I'm assuming you wish to change the math-mode font not only for numerals but for letters and symbols as well.

To employ Times Roman in math mode, you could load either a stand-alone math font package such as `mtpro2` -- aside: the full `mtpro2` package isn't free of charge -- in addition to the `times` package, or you could load an integrated package such as `mathptmx`, which changes both the text-mode font and the math-mode font to a Times Roman clone. (Aside: If you load `mathptmx`, you shouldn't load `times` as well.) Finally, you could stop loading `times` and load the *pair* of font packages `newtxtext` and `newtxmath`.

By the way, the `times` package changes not only the document's default serif font (to Times Roman) but also the default sans-serif font (to an Helvetica clone) and the default monospaced font (to Courier), via the following three commands:

```
\renewcommand{\sfdefault}{phv} % Helvetica
\renewcommand{\rmdefault}{ptm} % Times Roman
\renewcommand{\ttdefault}{pcr} % Courier
```

The `times` package offers no built-in method for scaling the sans-serif and monospaced fonts to better match the size of the serif font (Times Roman). If that's you really want, that's fine. But if you do not want to employ either Helvetica or Courier, you should probably not be loading the `times` package in the first place.